# What kind of CPU power do I get with Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, cpu-usage, autoscaling, azure-app-service-plans

I'm interested in deploying CPU intensive web app to an Azure App Service instance. I can't find any details around CPU usage and/or limits for Azure app service. My concern is that not having insight into the CPU specs/limitations for my app will not allow me to plan on how to accurately plan the physical cloud-based infrastructure (using Azure app service).

My app will be using the OpenCV computer vision library to do heavy image processing, face detection, and face recognition with hundreds/thousands of high quality images. This is naturally a CPU-intensive process. In a traditional setting (or on-premise Virtual Machine setup), I would at least know the specs on the machine (I.E. cpu specs, etc).

In summary, my question is two-fold:

1) Why doesn't azure app service say anything about the CPUs inside of their PaaS (App Service) context? If they do, where can i learn more about CPU limitations for this?

2) In the context of my application, is my CPU-based question irrelevant? I do read online that certain Azure App Service tiers do auto-scaling (meaning load balancing across more servers for better performance). Will this be sufficient for my need where multiple end-users are processing many photos to do face detection and recognition?

Comment: @AdrianBrand your link is specific to Azure VMs. I'm looking into App Services, which is a totally different offering. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

As i know standard app service are running on A Series VM but based on the scenario that you explained i suggest you to go with Premium App Service Plan that runs on Dv2 VM's. Hope below article will help you out:

I Suggest you to check the app service overview link and it says what kind of VM is running on back end so you can cross check with the VM specs and you can find the CPU details there.

[App Service Plan Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans)

[App Service Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)

[App Service Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft represent the performance of the a VM in terms of ACU (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/acu). There are limited number of VM's Available in Azure App Service plan.

App Service plan has both scale up and scale out option. Scale out can be done based on the different rules.
But always do remember that the application architecture will dictate how it will use the scale out option.

[image]

Note : I would suggest to use VM if it GPU or CPU intensive, as you will get more option.